# Show Table Details in Additional Row using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I've a html table that I would like to use a toggle to display additional information (and then push down the other rows).

Image to describe what I want to do: https://www.screencast.com/t/SBzG2IN9
On click toggle, show additional row (in green) and push the table down.

NOTE: The code below is not in HTML, but in the backend of WordPress Toolset. The [wpv-post-id] is a toolset variable that will output the wordpress postid on the front end. Eg, 1915, so data-prod-cat="1915" and the class becomes "cat1915".

[wpv-post-excerpt format="noautop"] also outputs the corresponding post excerpt in plain text (without

).

Update:
I've updated the code and the toggle button **manages to change the display** from **display:none** to **display: table-row**; however no new row shows up with the excerpt.

**Update 2:** Resolved!

Here's the loop output:

```
[wpv-layout-start]
    [wpv-items-found]
    <!-- wpv-loop-start -->
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>[wpv-heading name="types-field-release-date"]Year[/wpv-heading]</th>
                <th>[wpv-heading name="post-link"]Title[/wpv-heading]</th>
                <th>[wpv-heading name="types-field-publisher"]Publisher[/wpv-heading]</th>
                <th>[wpv-heading name="post-excerpt"]Synopsis[/wpv-heading]</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="wpv-loop js-wpv-loop">
        <wpv-loop>
            <tr>
                <td>[types field='release-date' style='text' format='Y'][/types]</td>
                <td>[wpv-post-link]</td>
                <td>[types field="publisher"][/types]</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat='[wpv-post-id]'><i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cat[wpv-post-id]" style="display:none" [wpv-post-excerpt format="noautop"]></tr>
        </wpv-loop>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <!-- wpv-loop-end -->
    [/wpv-items-found]
    [wpv-no-items-found]
        <strong>[wpml-string context="wpv-views"]No items found[/wpml-string]</strong>
    [/wpv-no-items-found]
[wpv-layout-end]
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery(".toggler").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
       jQuery('.cat'+jQuery(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you put this code in the snippet?

Comment: Here is the link: https://codepen.io/beans9/pen/WRveKO

Comment: Thank you @RevtiShah.

I just copied the source code from the page into that link.
Not exactly sure if I'm getting that right.

I added the html+JS there: https://codepen.io/beans9/pen/WRveKO

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: Hi @RevtiShah, unfortunately, not yet.

Comment: Okay I will help you out.

Comment: @RevtiShah Hi! Managed to resolve it already. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `[` and `]` in css selector or in class name. cause they are the default attribute selectors.

You must change your class to some thing with `A-Za-z0-9` charcters.

see [`attribute selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

when you want to select element with `.cat[wpv-post-excerpt]`. the browser think you want some thing like this:
                            `<tr class="cat" wpv-post-excerpt=""></tr>`

After that i think its the template variable and its not a really this `[wpv-post-excerpt]` string. see the result of your theme and do your job with them.

Comment: Ahhh I see! Thanks for your reply.

Hmm, how would I dynamically choose the right row to show then? The [wpv-post-excerpt] would output a paragraph in a loop.

I've got this code from here:
https://toolset.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/575006-Screen_Shot_2017_09_30_at_10.28.23_AM.png

Comment: @JonathanAng its the template variable and its not a really this `[wpv-post-excerpt]` string. see the result and do your job with them

Comment: thanks for the link! Yeah it's not really [wpv-post-excerpt] string, but the actual output is cat<p>The story revolves around Noh Ji-wook (Ji Chang-wook), a prosecutor, and Eun Bong-hee (Nam Ji-hyun), a prosecutor trainee, connected through a traumatic past and reunited in the present</p>

I'll try and mess around a bit. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Done!
Great hint here "You must change your class to some thing with A-Za-z0-9 charcters", so I tried postid instead of a paragraph output. It works.

Comment: @JonathanAng great. That the way ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that `tr` work as table row only when it is inside `table` tag. Second you can not take `[` or `]` in you selector. So please change your code according to that:

```
<table>
    <wpv-loop>
      <tr>
        <td>[types field='release-date' style='text' format='Y'][/types]</td>
        <td>[wpv-post-link]</td>
        <td>[types field="publisher"][/types]</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat='wpv-post-excerpt'><i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="cat-wpv-post-excerpt" style="display:none">
        <td colspan="100%">I m test</td>
      </tr>
    </wpv-loop>
</table>
```

And your js code is this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggler").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.cat-' + $(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).toggle();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try that.

The [ ] outputs a paragraph on the frontend though..would it be an issue?

Comment: @JonathanAng I don't think it is a issue.

Comment: thanks for your help!

That means class="cat[wpv-post-excerpt]" is actually okay?

The actual output looks like this:
cat<p>The story revolves around Noh Ji-wook (Ji Chang-wook), a prosecutor, and Eun Bong-hee (Nam Ji-hyun), a prosecutor trainee, connected through a traumatic past and reunited in the present</p>

does the <p> in the output affect the code?

Comment: @JonathanAng I did not understand your comment. Is my solution solve your concern?

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggler").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.cat-' + $(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).toggle();
  });
});
```

```
<wpv-loop>
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td>[types field='release-date' style='text' format='Y'][/types]</td>
    <td>[wpv-post-link]</td>
    <td>[types field="publisher"][/types]</td>
    <td><a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat='wpv-post-excerpt'><i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cat-wpv-post-excerpt" style="display:none">
   <td>all reacords</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</wpv-loop>
```

Comment: Thanks Kelvin. I'm not sure what am I supposed to here.

Change this 
<tr class="cat[wpv-post-excerpt]" style="display:none"></tr>
to
<tr class="cat-[wpv-post-excerpt]" style="display:none"></tr>?

And $('.cat'+jQuery(this) to $('.cat-'+jQuery(this)?

Answer (score 0):

Okay resolved!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery(".toggler").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
       jQuery('.cat'+jQuery(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).toggle();
    });
});
```

This code worked, but earlier answers indicate that the css selector doesn't work with []. But this is just a variable on the backend. However, [wpv-post-excerpt] outputs a very long paragraph and it didn't work as a selector either. So I used [wpv-post-id] which outputs the wordpress post id.

Here's the snippet of the code that worked:

```
<table>
        <wpv-loop>
            <tr>
                <td>[types field='release-date' style='text' format='Y'][/types]</td>
                <td>[wpv-post-link]</td>
                <td>[types field="publisher"][/types]</td>
                <td><a href="#" class="toggler" data-prod-cat='[wpv-post-id]'><i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="cat[wpv-post-id]" style="display:none">
            <td colspan="4">[wpv-post-excerpt]</td>
            </tr>
        </wpv-loop>
        </tbody>
</table>
```